# why does ionic storage does not work outside a function

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-storage

I am using ionic 2 with storage.
If I keep the storage code outside of a function it does not work.
kindly let me know.

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    public settings: Settings,
    public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public translate: TranslateService,
    private storage : Storage) {
  }  

this.settings.load().then(() => {
      this.settingsReady = true;
      this.options = this.settings.allSettings;

      this._buildForm();
    });

    this.storage.set('nam','par');
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor is a special function of the class that is responsible for initializing the variables of the class. `TypeScript` defines a constructor using the `constructor` keyword. A constructor is a function and hence can be parameterized. Up until the variable get's initialized it remains undefined. so, you can't do in that way and also make no sense, constructor is initialized before anything so either you can do the same operation within constructor or use any [life cycle event](http://blog.ionic.io/navigating-lifecycle-events/) in ionic to do so.